# Single Sign on in Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, single-sign-on

I have a Parent Application just a view where you can click different buttons to open the links embedded in it, which takes you to different asp.net applications. Problem is each of the application's basic authentication is set to true in IIS. How can i implement single sign on to save user to enter the password each time.

One solution is you make form authentication in each sites and in web config the machine key of the applications should be same. **I want to know is there any way that i can set Single sign on settings in the parent application in IIS?** as i dont want to distrub other applications code.

[image]

Comment: You won't be able to enable anything in IIS for single sign on. The best approach is the one you have mentioned. Then in the login pages for each of the sub apps, you set it up for redirection after it checks to see if authenticated or not.

Comment: Is there any other way other than form authentication, to do that i would have to make login pages in each application, which will be a big change.

Comment: You can use windows authentication too. Check this link out..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd577079.aspx

and check this link out..

http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/ssoformsauth

These are two links that I used to help set up my SSO.